# How do I get all table names where a column like 'column_name'. The catch is I want only table that have a specific value in the 'column_name'

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have no idea if there is a way to query a database like this. But basically I have a column name called = 'columnID' in about 100 tables in my database.

I am able to get all the table names by using this query:

```
SELECT c.name AS ColName, t.name AS TableName
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name LIKE '%columnID%';
```

But what if I have a specific value that I'm looking for, something like columnID = 11074.

Is there a way for me to somehow get tables name if there is at least one row of data with columnID = 11074? I know this is a shot in the dark. Looking for a friend here. 
Thanks.

Comment: You would have to use the query above to generate some dynamic SQL and run that, it's a bit nasty.

Comment: For example, you could do `SELECT 'SELECT * FROM '+t.Name+' WHERE columnID = 11074' FROM sys.columns c ....` and copy the output from there into the query window. If it's an ad-hoc statement, then this is an easy method.

Comment: yes, this is great. probably ad hoc, i dont see using this more than maybe a couple of times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a bit to get you started in the right direction.

```
WITH cteColumns AS (
    SELECT c.name AS ColName, t.name AS TableName, s.name AS SchemaName
    FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    JOIN sys.schemas s on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
    WHERE c.name LIKE '%columnnID%'
)
SELECT 'SELECT * FROM ' 
       + QUOTENAME(c.SchemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(c.TableName)
       + ' WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(c.ColName) + ' = 11074'
    FROM cteColumns c;
```

You could then dynamically execute these results or copy/paste to SSMS, depending on your needs.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to use @davidg ' s solution above but this will be handy!